# Background color on Google Sheets sparkline barchart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a 52-week indicator for my stock watchlist in Google sheets. I now have this:

[image]

The formula in column `C` is `=(A2-B2)/(E2-B2)`

The formula for the sparkline in column `D` is  `=SPARKLINE(C2,{"charttype","bar";"max",1})`

This works fine and as expected. But I would like to fill the full cell as follows:

[image]

I tried changing the background color of the cells as an easy fix, but it looks terrible:

[image]

I really need to define the right side of the bar itself with a different color and have each bar stretch over the full width of the cell.

How can I get the result I want? I hope that I'm making myself clear. The picture hopefully shows what I want.

Comment: I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet or a copy of it. Right now, there aren't any ranges showing; and it will be easier to show than to tell. You should also be able to get all sparklines returned with a single formula.

Comment: Hi Erik, and thanks for you comment. I have created a sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AAR9jCWceAqINkogcj-ydJB63b0LygdLZ6-8b9FMbzw/edit?usp=sharing. Will this help?

Comment: Would [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPrrm.gif) be ideal for you? It seems you need to plot an 

array containing two data, the other one to be the fixed maximum (e.g. 100).

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 that is absolutely perfect, thank you so much! As a separate question: would it be possible to have one formula (in D2) filling the range for each row, instead of a dragged-down formula (and each row its own formula)?

Answer (score 1):

#### SUGGESTION

In my understanding, if you're aiming to create **sparkline** bar chart with two different color separations and you wish to use just one formula *(in D2)* to fill the range for each row, rather than dragging-down the formula *(where each row has its own formula)*, you can experiment with the following method:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(C2:C17), 1, LAMBDA(row_index, column_index, SPARKLINE({INDIRECT("C"&row_index + 1), 100},{"charttype", "bar"; "max", 1})))
```

This solution addresses the following challenges:

1. Using an array that contains two data points in your **sparkline**, with one being a fixed maximum *(e.g., 100)*, to achieve bar charts with two different color separations.
2. Employing [**MAKEARRAY**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569202) along with the **sparkline** function that will contain the [**INDIRECT**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) function to enable the utilization of just one formula *(in D2)* to populate the range for each row.

##### Sample Result

[image: Sample Result]

## References

- [MAKEARRAY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569202)
- [INDIRECT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

Comment: @Pr0no I just added this answer suggesting a way for you to use a single formula to automatically populate the rows within your specified range. I'm hoping this helps.